# std::shared_ptr Iterator

Tags: c++

I have an iterator which iterates over a std::shared_ptr. So operator++ points the internally stored shared pointer to the next item.

```
template<class IT>
class MyIterator
{
public:
    ...

    MyIterator& operator++()
    {
        _i = ... // Call factory
        return *this;
    }
private:
    std::shared_ptr<IT> _i;
};
```

How should I implement the operator*() and operator->() operators?

How should I test if the iterator is pointing to NULL, i.e. if the internal shared pointer is pointing to NULL.

Comment: Why would your iterator test if the shared_ptr is NULL?  Other iterators don't do that.

Comment: You're right. I was getting confused here. Instead I should do this: if (i==end()) to test if it is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define under what circumstances users are permitted to deference an instance of your class. Usually this is "anything other than an end iterator or an uninitialized iterator".

Then you should ensure that `_i` never contains a null pointer for an instance that can be dereferenced.

This means there is no need for a check, because the user is not permitted to call `operator*` or `operator->` in that circumstance. You could add one for debugging, for example: `assert(_i.get());`.

You don't specify what the `value_type` is of your iterator, but assuming that it is `IT`, you can implement:

```
IT &operator*() { return *_i; }
shared_ptr<IT> operator->() { return _i; }
// or
IT *operator->() { return _i.get(); }
```